# How can I detect if a new listener is registered?

Tags: angularjs

If another piece of code calls `$scope.$on`, I'd like my service to be notified of this so it can subscribe to a websocket with the same named channel.  Is there an event on `$rootScope` that I can listen for or an expression I can $watch?

I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/polidore/AZ7Av/

Where I'm `$watching` `Object.keys($scope.$$listeners).length`, but it doesn't seem to get called aside from the initial load.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `$on`, the best way is to make your own function which calls `$on` for you while notifying your service.

If you you really need to detect it via the `$on` function, then you can override the function like this:

```
var old$on = $scope.$on;
$scope.$on = function(name, listener) {
    // Code to notify your service here

    old$on.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to do this for a library.  I guess I could just make users register events via my service, but it would be nice syntactic sugar to let them use the normal API and have the registrations automatically hook into my service if it's injected.

Comment: Thanks, Kranklin. I have used the override method in this jsfiddle.

Comment: I used this method in the following project: https://github.com/polidore/ss-angular  More to come.